# How to do aggregated query base on a condition?

Tags: soql

I have an 'Job' object, and I want to group and count the job records into two groups:
1. jobs that created before certain date
2. jobs that created after certain date

Can I achieve this via soql aggregated query?
Something like:

```
List<AggregatedResult> results = [select count(Id) From Job__c Group By CreatedDate > {certainDate}];
```

Comment: I think you'll either need two SOQL calls or to process it in Apex afterward. . .

Comment: you will definitely need two queries if you stick with aggregate-result .Using normal query, you can declare two variables and use simple if and else statement and use counter to increment .

Answer (score 1):

If your criteria date is fixed here is what i would do:

1. Create new field say "Group_type" update this field based on criteria using Trigger/ workflow
2. use this Group_type field in query for grouping
   `List<AggregatedResult> results = [Select count(Id) From Job__c Group By Group_type ];`
3. This should give you same result with with one query
4. Note that it will return both groups in different rows but you can write apex logic around it to get the data.

Comment: the date is dynamic

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can probably do this in one query with just a tiny bit of tweaking! First, using `count()` will give you all the records. Using `count(field name)` with a `where condition` returns only the count records that meet the `where criteria`.

I suggest you try something like this:

```
List<AggregatedResult> results = [select count(), count(Id), CreatedDate From Job__c Group By Count(Id) where CreatedDate < {certainDate} and CreatedDate >= {CertainDate} ];
```

Note that count() gives you the total number of records, **>=** gives you the count for Id's created **on or after** `CertainDate` **<** returns the records created **before** {certain date}. The two of them should sum to the number of total records in `count()`.

I've not tested this to confirm it will work for your particular situation, but based on some of the examples in the [SOQL documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/index.htm), this should give you the results you're looking for. If it doesn't, I'd recommend doing what Mohith has suggested.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the amount of `Job__c` records created after and before certain date I think that you **don't** need to use `group by`

I'd perform this:

```
Integer amountBefore = [select count() From Job__c Where CreatedDate < :certainDate];
Integer amountAfter = [select count() From Job__c Where CreatedDate >= :certainDate];
```

Comment: this is what I did in the end.

Comment: @bluecat If this is the right answer, you'd probably should mark it as accepted, in order to guide futures users whose look for the same question: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I would consider this as a walk around . The question is about retrieving and grouping within one soql query...

Comment: In your question is not clear if you need the affected records, do you? What is AggregatedResult[] ?